# Icefaces2.0 - Problem when login again after a logout

Tags: hibernate, spring, icefaces, logout

I am developing with IceFaces 2.0 + Spring 2.5 + jpa1.0/Hibernate 3.2.5 
I have a problem that I cannot solve, I hope in your cleverness!

I am developing a web application that, obviously, has login/logout functionality. The problem is that, if I login after I did a logout, I have a behaviour completely absurd and sometimes unpredictable: popups does not close no more, a lot of buttons does not work, etc... But, on the first login, everything is all right!

I also tried o remove manually all of my beans session scoped, nothing. I tried to logout from IE8, and then login from Firefox, the problem persists. Any ideas?

This is the code of the Logout servlet:

```
 HttpSession session = (HttpSession) request.getSession(false);
 if(session != null) {
    session.invalidate();
    try {
        response.sendRedirect("/" + request.getContextPath() + "/" + PRIMA_PAGINA);
         } catch (IOException e) {
    }
 }
```

Should I use, instead

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().invalidateSession();
```

from a bean method? I did try, but the problem is always the same.

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know if you still have the issue:

```
    HttpServletRequest request = 
        (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest(); 
    request.getSession().invalidate(); 
    request.getSession(true);
```

Comment: hmmm. let's choose a specific component and focus in on it. So you log into the app and a specific button works fine. After you log out and log back in that specific button no longer works. Can you post the code to that specific button and describe exactly what doesn't work (do you click it and nothing happens or does it not hit an action method etc.)?

Comment: I did solve it! I was completely wrong in thinking that the problem were in the logout methods. The problem was on the second login, also if another user accessed the system before the first one logout! It was due to the fact that a window scoped backing bean was referencig a session bean using a static variable. So, substantially, the second user "shared" a session bean of the other user and the behaviour seemed absurd, but motivated!

Comment: awesome. glad you figured it out. i hate mysterious issues like that, they are a real time leech.